# How would you say "I fell asleep!" in Esperanto?

Tags: esperanto-speakers

I have no reason to know this. I just want to.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify the phrase you are asking about. "I feel asleep" is ungrammatical English and it's not clear what you mean. Do you mean "I fell asleep" (meaning you were awake and then you were not awake); or do you mean "I feel sleepy" (meaning you are still awake but are tired and want to sleep)?

Comment: Welcome to [esperanto.SE] Stack Exchange! Please [edit] your question to make it more clear. Currently we don't know whether you meant "I feel sleepy" (I'm tired and might fall asleep) or "I fell asleep" (I was awake, but then, not anymore) or something different. ("I feel asleep" probably isn't correct English, so we can't know what it would mean or how to translate it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a total gamma of fixed (English) verbal expressions that can use **ek-**

- I fell asleep = **mi ekdormis/endormiĝis**
- I feel sleepy = **mi sentas min dormema** / **mi estas dormema**

An other **ek-** case I could construe:

- I caught a cold - **mi malvarmumiĝis** / **ekmalvarmumis**